# Using awk how do I replace a word in a file with unique values?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

This is the file I want to use:

test.txt:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  app_username: something
  app_password: {{RANDOM}}
  another_app_username: something
  another_app_password: {{RANDOM}}
```

I currently have this bash script:

test.sh:

```
random(){
  printf $(openssl rand -base64 15) | openssl base64
}

export -f random

awk '{ 
  gsub(/{{RANDOM}}/, system("random"), $0); printf
}' test.txt
```

This outputs:

```
TVQ3K0hmZmZGMTBPYW9BT0pIbzc=
apiVersion: v1QlBXZzVFNXFUdzBXNzdwdmtWc2w=
data:eDJDcUZKU1U2d1EwaWc5cVhQYUY=
  app_username: somethingay93S3NTNStQKy9jVXFOUHBSZnY=
  app_password: 0NTBJTUpueWRuU1VZYmlWSXZwS0k=
  another_app_username: somethingdzdCWXltMytSUWRFY2RicVh5ZkI=
  another_app_password: 0%
```

As you can see, it's doing *something*. It's removing {{RANDOM}} but not replacing it. Instead it's putting the output of the 'random' function at the end of every new line.

Comment: `printf $(openssl rand -base64 15)` what is the point of `printf`? Just `openssl rand -base64 15`. In `awk` the `system("random")` does __not__ get the output of a command, it just executes the command. So it just executes the command at each line

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the explanation I understand it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
awk 'function rndm(cmd, line, r) {
   cmd = "random"
   if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0)
      r=line
   close(cmd)
   return r
}
{
   gsub(/{{RANDOM}}/, rndm())
} 1' file
```

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  app_username: something
  app_password: blBVOFduMzRLSEtSWjlRK0czT1M=
  another_app_username: something
  another_app_password: WWtZb1dWN2tnN0NwZEo1NTB2ZHE=
```